# How to move a button within a table head column

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to move the buttons within a thead by few pixels so it can sit on a border bottom line color below it...

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <!-- table extra buttons -->
    <tr style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #FFE84D; border-bottom-width: 4px;">
      <th>
        <div class="mx-auto" style="background-color: #FFE84D; border-radius: 2px;">
          <button class="btn bg-default btn-sm">username</button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="mx-auto" style="background-color: #FFE84D; border-radius: 2px;">
          <button type="button" class="btn bg-default btn-sm">something else </button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="mx-auto" role="button" style="background-color: #FFE84D; border-radius: 4px;">
          <button class="btn bg-default btn-sm">time</button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <!-- table extra buttons end -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS - and a picture perhaps. It is not clear what you want

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <!-- table extra buttons -->
    <tr >
      <th>
        <div class="mx-auto" style="background-color: #FFE84D; border-radius: 2px;">
          <button class="btn bg-default btn-sm">username</button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="mx-auto" style="background-color: #FFE84D; border-radius: 2px;">
          <button type="button" class="btn bg-default btn-sm">something else </button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="mx-auto" role="button" style="background-color: #FFE84D; border-radius: 4px;">
          <button class="btn bg-default btn-sm">time</button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <!-- table extra buttons end -->
    </tr>
 <tr>
 <th colspan='3' style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #FFE84D; border-bottom-width: 4px;"></th>
 </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```